# Windows 7 corrupt file

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

Error:
\windows\system\drivers\atapi.sys

Status: 0xc000000f

I think I will lose my data.

[image: Windows Boot Manager Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an essential Windows driver is corrupted or missing.
`atapi.sys` handles IDE disks, which in your case is probably the
Windows disk.

I suggest using a Linux Live USB to save any unbacked-up data.

Then you could follow the article
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

If you manage to get Windows 7 booting, your first action should be
to check the status of the disk, in case it needs to be replaced.
Checking the SMART data of the disk (if the disk isn't too old)
is the first step. If you don't have a utility for that, see
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).